# Code keeps freezing whenever I compile it in Netbeans

Tags: java

I'm still quite new to java and NetBeans and I encountered this problem recently. I've tried compiling my code multiple times now but its not working. It keeps getting stuck at exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli). My code is for used to convert celsius to fahrenheit.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter a degree in Celsius: ");
        double celsius = input.nextDouble();
        
        double fahrenheit = (9.0 / 5.0) * celsius + 32;
        
        System.out.println(celsius + " Celsius is " + fahrenheit + " Fahrenheit");
    }
}
```

The program should have loaded fine since it worked with a simple hello world program.This is the error I have been receiving the entire time.

```
Scanning for projects...

------------------------< com.mycompany:demmo >-------------------------
Building demo 1.0-SNAPSHOT
--------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ demmo ---
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\demmo\src\main\resources

--- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ demmo ---
Changes detected - recompiling the module!
Compiling 1 source file to D:\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\demmo\target\classes

--- exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) @ demmo ---
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>demmo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <name>demo</name>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you post the part of your pom.xml that is relevant to the `exec-maven-plugin`?

Comment: I'm not sure you really get any advantage using maven for a java program as simple as yours. Are you required to use maven to build your project or trying to learn maven? If not I would think about just compiling and running this simple class as a standard non-maven project.

Comment: @f1sh I'm not sure if this is it

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS My university course requires me to use the Netbeans compiler for my projects, and honestly I'm don't really know what maven does either

Comment: Try typing the answer in the output window (even without seeing a prompt!) If it works (and prints the prompt afterwards) then it's the Netbeans bug reported above.

Comment: @k314159 I followed the instructions on the link you provided me and it worked! I didn't expect it to be a bug from Netbeans itself though, I've been trying to figure this out for hours, thank you so much!

Comment: Post your additional details as edits to your Question rather than as Comments.